# How can I define a custom primary key in web2py

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, web2py, data-access-layer

I'm building a simple application in web2py which will be used to store some data in tables using a web based form.

The following code is an example of a table related to a drop down menu.

```
#########################################################################
## Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion
db.define_table('Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion',
            Field('num_tenencia','integer', required='TRUE'),
            Field('nombre_tenencia', 'text', required='TRUE'))

if db(db.Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion.id>0).count() == 0:
db.Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion.insert(num_tenencia='1',nombre_tenencia='Ejidal')
db.Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion.insert(num_tenencia='2',nombre_tenencia='Comunal')
db.Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion.insert(num_tenencia='3',nombre_tenencia='Propiedad particular')
db.Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion.insert(num_tenencia='4',nombre_tenencia='Propiedad federal')
```

However this application will be passed around several collegues and thus autogenerated IDs may represent a problem when trying to gather all the information they will individually collect.

I would like to declare as primary key the field 'num_tenencia' but apparently web2py doesn't allow it, as the primary key must be autogenerated. As you can see in the code above, 'num_tenencia' is unique to every record.

¿Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
db.define_table('Conglomerado_tenencia_opcion',
    Field('num_tenencia','integer', required=True),
    Field('nombre_tenencia', 'text', required=True),
    primarykey=['num_tenencia'])
```

However, this is not recommended, as it limits some of the web2py functionality (for more details, see the book section on [keyed tables](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Legacy-databases-and-keyed-tables)).

In any case, even if you set your own primary key, if different versions of the app will be running on different systems, you will still have to come up with a scheme to ensure there are no duplicates across systems (perhaps uuid's).

As an alternative, you might be better off creating a workflow to combine data from the separate databases. In fact, the web2py documentation provides a [recipe](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#CSV-and-remote-database-synchronization) for just such a workflow.